# Spring Rest delete 404

Tags: spring, rest

I have rest controller and rest client. GET, POST, PUT works perfectly, but DELETE redirect on 404.

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/category/delete/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public void delete(@PathVariable("id") Long categoryId) {
    Category category = categoryRepository.findOne(categoryId);
    if (category == null)
        throw new CategoryInDatabaseIsEmpty(categoryId);
    categoryRepository.delete(category);
}
```

and client

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/categories/delete/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String deleteCategory(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        restTemplate.delete(http://localhost:8080/InternetShop/rest/category/delete/ + id);
    return "redirect:/categories/page/" + 1;
}
```

Any suggestions about this?

Comment: You have to append first id before passing to rest template method.

Comment: what do you mean by appending? 
"String url = UrlRestUtil.DELETE_CATEGORY + id;
restTemplate.delete(url); "

and how exectly this can help?

Comment: Yeah passed the url string .

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work